# Latex figure next to text and text align right

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, text

In my LaTeX document I would like to align a figure on the bottom-left-hand side of page while, at the same height, some text aligned to the right side of the page.

Code below is what I got so far.. With this, the figure is positioned lower than the text. Any solution to this? I have been struggling on this for hours; answers will be highly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{minipage}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
        \hfill{Rule 1 ...}\\
        \hfill{Rule 2 ...}\\
        \hfill{Rule 3 ...}\\
    \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need *only two minipages without a blank line* between them (but it is fine insert  some space as `\hfill` or `\quad`). To left both at the bottom, you can use  `\vfill` (or a `figure` environment with the `[b]` option, if the figure and text can float to another page)

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```